# Mover comentarios al chat

Tags: soporte, comentarios, chat

Mi duda es ¿cómo puedo mover los comentarios de una pregunta al chat? Para que no esté tan "aparatoso" y no sea tan difícil de leer.

Comment: no puedes, pero los moderadores diamantados pueden. nadie deberia conversar en comentarios ;)

Comment: Hay que andar molestando para esa feature jejeje

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Bajo ciertas circunstancias de manera automática aparece un enlace para continuar la discusión en una sala de chat. Se moverían a una sala de chat nueva.

Si no te ha aparecido el enlace para mover los comentarios, por ejemplo, podría ser porque el autor de la pregunta no tiene la reputación sufiente para participar en el chat, como ha indicado gbianchi en un comentario a la pregunta, sólo los moderadores diamantados pueden mover los comentarios bajo demanda.

Si ves que hay comentarios intrascendentales o que se han vuelto obsoletos, por ejemplo un comentario solicitando código una vez que se ha editado la pregunta para agregar el código solicitado ya no se requiere, puedes reportarlo como "Ya no es necesario" sin pena alguna ya que no hay penalización en este caso de reportes. Los comentarios que tiene ciertas palabras clave podrían eliminarse de inmediato, en otros casos deberán haber varios reportes "Ya no es necesario" para que se eliminen.